# How do I break the text in a table-cell?

Tags: line-breaking, cell

I am using Tufte book. For the table below, I want to add a line break in the first column. I want "Nr. of transactions" to be in one line and "pre-processing" on the second line. How do I force a line break in a cell?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Characteristics of the datasets}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{ | m{3cm} | m{3cm}| m{3cm} | } 
  \hline
  Characteristics & Scandinavian retail  & UK-based retail \\ 
  \hline
  Nr. of transactions (pre-processing)  & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
  \hline
  Nr. of unique customers (pre-processing)  & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
  Nr. of unique items (pre-processing)  & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \label{Datachar}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Just use this code for the cell: `Nr. of transactions \newline (pre-processing)`.

Comment: This is the default if you declare `\usepackage{array}` in the preamble. You should have presented a minimal working example.

Comment: You can use the package `makecell`